elasticsearch Dependency failed to fetch from repo maven - maven project
Java version: 22
Springboot version: 3.3.5
Apache Maven: 3.8.1

I am currently trying to fetch elasticsearch java API from repo maven
        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.16.1</version>
        </dependency>

I manually check from mvnrepository.com to make sure it exists and it is: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/co.elastic.clients/elasticsearch-java/8.16.1
however, when i try to run mvn clean install -X I got this error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ElasticService: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:ElasticService:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:jar:8.14.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:jar:8.14.1: Could not transfer artifact co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:pom:8.14.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch-java/8.14.1/elasticsearch-java-8.14.1.pom: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.232.44.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project ElasticService: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:ElasticService:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:jar:8.14.1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:269)
    ...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:ElasticService:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:jar:8.14.1
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:178)
    ...
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:jar:8.14.1
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:288)
    ...
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:jar:8.14.1
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    ...
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:pom:8.14.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch-java/8.14.1/elasticsearch-java-8.14.1.pom
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:424)
    ...
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:pom:8.14.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch-java/8.14.1/elasticsearch-java-8.14.1.pom
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed (ArtifactTransportListener.java:52)
    ...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch-java/8.14.1/elasticsearch-java-8.14.1.pom
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1250)
    ...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.232.44.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect (DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
    ...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0 (Native Method)
    ...

At first, I thought it was due to proxy however when I delete that dependency and add another libray - it succesfully installed. So, surely it is not due to the proxy right? For reverence the other library that success installed after this particular library got this error is com.fasterxml.jackson.core jackson-databing
What did I miss? What should I check to fix this?
/edit I tried doing it on public wifi with no proxy and I got this error
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.maven.apache.org

//edit: This is my whole pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ElasticService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ElasticService</name>
    <description>ElasticService</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5</version> <!-- Use the latest compatible version -->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.16.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.parsson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>parsson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Can you share full pom.xml file also maven settings that you have ? , because I suppose there can be some misconfiguration. Also if I had the same problem I would try enabling the proxy on the code editor level(for instance IntelliJ IDEA)

@AndreiLisa I have added the full pom.xml on my initial post

I have tried to run with the above pom.xml and I can say the problem you have is related to a network not the maven or dependencies
